# Python CountVectorizer for Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, countvectorizer

I have got a pandas dataframe which looks like the following:

```
 df.head()
                                categorized.Hashtags
 0    icietmaintenant supyoga standuppaddleportugal ...
 1    instapaysage bretagne labellebretagne bretagne...
 2    bretagne lescrepescestlavie quimper bzh labret...
 3    bretagne mer paysdiroise magnifique phare plou...
 4    bateaux baiededouarnenez voiliers vieuxgreemen..
```

Now instead of using pandas get_dummmies() command I would like to use CountVectorizer to create the same output. Because get_dummies takes too much time.

```
df_x = df["categorized.Hashtags"]
vect = CountVectorizer(min_df=0.,max_df=1.0)
X = vect.fit_transform(df_x)
count_vect_df = pd.DataFrame(X.todense(), columns = vect.get_feature_names())
```

When I now output the respective data frame "count_vect_df" then the data frame contains a lot of columns which are empty/ contains only zero values. How can I avoid this?

Cheers,
Andi

Answer (score -1):

From [`scikit-learn CountVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) docs:

> Convert a collection of text documents to a matrix of token counts
>
> This implementation produces a sparse representation of the counts
>   using scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.

The `CountVectorizer` returns a `sparse-matrix`, which contains most of zero values, where non-zero values represent the number of times that specific term has appeared in the particular document.